# from which database comes a .idb format?

Tags: database, rdbms

I want to import to read and convert a database in .idb format . I was told that this file comes from a IBM tool used on indows 98. I do not know exactly from which tool.

I have the following files

a .idb file of 1Go size which was called directly by the application using this database with this call procedure
SERVER NAME=localhost:C:\BELAIR3\APPSER\APPSER.IDB

a .db file
a .lck file
a .mb file
a .px file

a .sql file with some procedures, here is the beginning:

```
CONNECT "localhost:C:\BELAIR3\appser\APPSER.IDB"
USER SYSDBA PASSWORD masterkey;
set term ^ ;

CREATE PROCEDURE CHERCHENOMDPP(
    NUMERO INTEGER
)
RETURNS (
    NOMDPP VARCHAR(50)
)
AS
  DECLARE VARIABLE vnom VARCHAR(50);
  DECLARE VARIABLE vprenom VARCHAR(50);
  DECLARE VARIABLE vnombre INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT b_nom,b_prenom FROM DPPSER
    WHERE b_numdpp = :numero
    INTO :vnom, :vprenom;
  if (vnom is  null) then
    nomdpp = "???";
  else if (vprenom is null) then
    nomdpp = vnom;
  else
    nomdpp = vnom||" "||vprenom;
  SUSPEND;
END ^
```

Comment: According to the first google response for `IBM .idb`, this might be "iBase Designer" https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSXVXZ_2.2.0/com.ibm.i2.ibase.admin.doc/creating_databases_in_detail.html

Comment: seems difficult. the database was used on windows 98

Comment: The idb file is an Interbase file and it can be opened with Firebird